# AppDomains and debug symbols

Tags: c#

I have a project in which I'm using AppDomains with a very restricted PermissionSet.

The problem is that, if an exception occurs inside the AppDomain, the StackTrace property of the Exception object contains the names of the methods in the stack trace, but not the line numbers, despite the fact that the PDB data has been loaded into the assembly within the AppDomain.

In the course of debugging, I found that if I made the following change to my permission set, then line numbers start appearing in the stack trace:

```
PermissionSet permSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted);    // Was PermissionState.None
permSet.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));

AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Sandbox", null, new AppDomainSetup {......}, permSet);
```

Obviously the downside of setting the permission set to be unrestricted is that the code that runs in this AppDomain can now do whatever it wants, so although this lets me see the line numbers in the stack trace, it's not an acceptable solution. I'm figuring that there must be a specific permission I need to add to the permission set - but I can't for the life of me figure out what permission that is.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here, or even better, tell me what permission I need to add? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, not sure if it will help, but looking at the source code for the StackTrace class (i hope the stacktrace in an exception is obtained in the same manner) reveals that it seems to need ReflectionPermission with member access and SecurityPermission for unmanaged code (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/4e7f1f734a435f15.html) Try adding those permissions to your PermissionSet and see what happens (if it happens to work, you might self-answer your question ;-) )

Comment: No joy I'm afraid, but thanks for the answer. I had tried each of those individually, but not together, so I was hopeful - but just tried it, and it doesn't work.

Comment: However... you have pointed me towards the source code, and I'm now looking at the code for the Exception class: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/exception.cs,fd7466f7c15d31c7 - it says in there that it needs FileIOPermission(PathDiscovery), and that seems to be getting me along the right lines. 

(What I mean by "along the right lines" is that setting all FileIOPermissions works! But if I set only the PathDiscovery option, I need to specify a file, and I'm working on that. My PDB is a byte array, not a file. But I'm close now, so thank you!)

Comment: There is a FileIOPermission constructor that doesn't need a path: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Security_Permissions_FileIOPermission__ctor_System_Security_Permissions_PermissionState_. Unless you want to restrict file IO permissions. In that case, perhaps create a separate (temp) folder with a copy the PDB file (from the PDB byte array) and give file IO permission to this path only. (Not sure, though, whether this would be feasible for your use case...)

Comment: All sorted. There is indeed such a constructor - you can't set PathDiscovery using it, but once you've got the FileIOPermission object you can add PathDiscover to its AllFiles property. However, I've found that the main constructor works when I pass the path of the current executing assembly - I have no idea why, but it works and I'm not complaining. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the comments, the solution was hiding in the source code of the Exception object, and it is that you need to add FileIOPermission(PathDiscovery).

Comment: Can you share a short example of how you add this permission?

Comment: I can do better, I can point you to the exact code. https://github.com/ddashwood/CodingTrainer/blob/master/CodeHost/CodeRunner.SandboxManager.cs line 173. Hope that helps.

Comment: are you sure the AppDomain is configured correctly? If `IsFullyTrusted` returns `true` then I guess not. See also my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69726316/bug-in-net-framework-mscorlib-preventing-stack-trace-line-numbers) on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this section in app.config helps

```
<runtime><SymbolReadingPolicy enabled="1" /></runtime>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).